# Preventing duplicate entry for object class to a listbox as item

Tags: c#, listbox, duplicates

I am trying to add an item from an object class into a list box and check if the item already exists on the list box. If so then I just remove the current item and replace it with the current object (which will just increase the quantity and price) but for some reason the if statement is always true as in, I am checking if the item name exists already and is always coming up with its not (even though it is).

Here is my attempt below:

```
 private void AddListItem(OrderItem item)
 {
     if (!lstOrderPad.Items.Contains(item.Name))
     {
         lstOrderPad.Items.Add(string.Format("{0,-5}{1,-15}{2,-10}",
             item.Quantity, item.Name, item.ItemPrice));
     }
     else
     {
         int index = lstOrderPad.Items.IndexOf(item);
         lstOrderPad.Items.RemoveAt(index);
         lstOrderPad.Items.Add(string.Format("{0,-5}{1,-15}{2,-10}",
             item.Quantity, item.Name, item.ItemPrice));
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what values present in `lstOrderPad.Items` and what are you trying to add into list i.e. value of `item.Name`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are adding a formatted string to list, but comparing with only the `Name` property.

You are adding following string to List

```
string.Format("{0,-5}{1,-15}{2,-10}", item.Quantity, item.Name, item.ItemPrice)
```

But comparing with

```
if (lstOrderPad.Items.Contains(item.Name))
```

You should instead for the following

```
var itemFormat = string.Format("{0,-5}{1,-15}{2,-10}", item.Quantity, item.Name, item.ItemPrice);
if (!lstOrderPad.Items.Contains(itemFormat))
{
    lstOrderPad.Items.Add(itemFormat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!lstOrderPad.Items.Contains(item.Name))
```

This will always be true if None of the items/string contain exact item.Name. Every item of yours is a "{x,y},{a,b}"... never JUST "x".

if you change the query to below, you will check every item in the list of items to see if the name is part of it.

```
var itemWithSameName = lstOrderPad.Items.Where(eachItem = eachItem.Contains(item.Name)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now you can check if the itemWithSameName is null or not to replace it. BUT, you store each of the elements as a string. Not sure how you plan to determine which part of the string is quantity that you will update. You should definitely look into a class that can help you store these values.

Something like...

```
public class Order
{
    public Order ()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>();
    }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

This gives you more flexibility in queries and updates to items. Hope it helps.

Comment: What is x referring to? also, this function is only sorting out the functionality for the list box there are other functions that are taking care of the item object of a class.

Comment: Where function iterated through the list and x becomes each item. This is a linq statement that helps with for loops

Comment: @YousifThamer Did this answer your question?